# rails 3: best SQL query to list + count all existing values of a field?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a SQL query for rails 3/active records that does most/all the work to fill an array or hash with all the values (and counts) that a field contains?

For example, a list (and count) of all the city names that customers are in:

If customer.city contains dallas, paris, chicago, dallas, houston, dallas, paris

I need to generate the list

```
chicago 1
dallas 3
houston 1
paris 2
```

Of course it's easy to do it by iterating, but I'm thinking there's a way to most/all the work in a good SQL query?

Comment: We need either model declarations or table declarations to really help. Are you looking for number of customers per city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused... do you mean like this?

```
Customer.group('city').count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT city_name, count(city_name) FROM customers GROUP BY city_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`def dup_hash

    inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,e| h[e] += 1; h }.select {

      |k,v| v > 0 }.inject({}) { |r, e| r[e.first] = e.last; r }

end

puts customer.city.dup_hash`

You can try this in irb.

Comment: Sorry  i didn't got any Sql query.

Comment: Thank you, although i think that woudl be less efficient since it has to iterate through the database.